# Page components/modules in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, components

Is it possible to write ASP.NET (.NET 4) application using reusable page components?

I meant something like code snippets, pluggable into multiple pages, like login form, for example, witch handles its own post requests. This snippet then use in homepage and login page. This is just example, but I hope it can demonstrate what I am talking about.

Are here any prepared classes for do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UserControl`.

Link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx

Also you can use `CustomControl` or `MasterPage`